# Why Cronjob doesn't work in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: server, cron

My cronjob doesn't work in Ubuntu Server 18.04. Can someone help me?
Here is my cron code:

```
#This code doesn't run
* * * * * root sh /home/jaka/scripts/serviceChecker.sh
#I have try this below but doesn't work too
* * * * * /home/jaka/sripts/serviceChecker.sh
#I have try the code below but also doesn't work
* * * * * sh /home/jaka/scripts/serviceChecker.sh
```

serviceCheker.sh is executable and success. But when i try to use that with cronjob is doen't work.

Here is serviceChecker.sh code:

```
 #This code below is successful
 dateTime=$(date +"%A, %b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")
 if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep mysql > /dev/null
 then
 echo "$dateTime MySql is running" >> logServiceStatus.txt
 else
 echo "$dateTime MySql is stopped" >> logServiceStatus.txt
 sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql
 echo "$dateTime Mysql is running again" >> logServiceStatu.txt
 #.................................(And so on)
```

I hope someone can help me or give me the answer.

Comment: If this is a user crontab, the first entry is wrong. If it is a `root` crontab, the other entries are wrong. Run this cronjob (once), and look at the results: `00 14  *   *   *     (echo "=== set ===";set;echo "===env ==="; env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias) >cron.environment` . Run the commands in an environment where `/home/jaka/sripts/serviceChecker.sh` works (put theoutput in a different file). then compare. The environments differ.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this problem.

So, the serviceChecker.sh is have sudo command and the problem is crontab can't asking the password for sudo.
when you make a log for this .sh files it write:

```
 sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

i fix this by give the user (username is jaka) permission to run it without asking sudo password. How to do this? Here is the step:

```
sudo visudo
```

then below #includedir /etc/sudoers.d write this:

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

example

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
jaka ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

its will cronjob's sudo without input password.